# How do I make my jQuery countdown code work

Tags: jquery, html

This is a simple jQuery Countdown code for my website, which is supposed to countdown till the midnight of 1st April 2019. Here is the relevant part of the jQuery and HTML code. The problem is that the timer doesn't count after running. Any suggestion about the problem and methods to rectify the code in the snippet below will be of great help to me.

```js
function makeTimer() {

  var endTime = new Date("01 April 2019 9:56:00 GMT+01:00");   
  endTime = (Date.parse(endTime) / 1000);

  var now = new Date();
  now = (Date.parse(now) / 1000);

  var timeLeft = endTime - now;

  var days = Math.floor(timeLeft / 86400); 
  var hours = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400)) / 3600);
  var minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600 )) / 60);
  var seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)));

  if (hours < "10") { hours = "0" + hours; }
  if (minutes < "10") { minutes = "0" + minutes; }
  if (seconds < "10") { seconds = "0" + seconds; }

  $(".days").html(days + "<br><span>days</span>");
  $(".hours").html(hours + "<br><span>hours</span>");
  $(".minutes").html(minutes + "<br><span>minutes</span>");
  $(".seconds").html(seconds + "<br><span>seconds</span>");  

}

setInterval(function() { makeTimer(); }, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="row countdown-box" style="top: 0px">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2 id="countdown" class="days">24<br>                        <span>days</span></h2>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2 id="countdown">:</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2 id="countdown" class="hours">06<br><span>hours</span></h2>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2 id="countdown">:</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2 id="countdown" class="minutes">22<br><span>minutes</span></h2>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2 id="countdown">:</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2 id="countdown" class="seconds">59<br><span>seconds</span></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hint: most of the selectors you pass to jquery don't match anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create extra function inside setInterval, just pass the function name

```
setInterval(makeTimer, 1000)
```

Fixed html

```js
function makeTimer() {

  var endTime = new Date("01 April 2019 9:56:00 GMT+01:00");   
  endTime = (Date.parse(endTime) / 1000);

  var now = new Date();
  now = (Date.parse(now) / 1000);

  var timeLeft = endTime - now;

  var days = Math.floor(timeLeft / 86400); 
  var hours = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400)) / 3600);
  var minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600 )) / 60);
  var seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)));

  if (hours < "10") { hours = "0" + hours; }
  if (minutes < "10") { minutes = "0" + minutes; }
  if (seconds < "10") { seconds = "0" + seconds; }

  $(".days").html(days + "<br><span>days</span>");
  $(".hours").html(hours + "<br><span>hours</span>");
  $(".minutes").html(minutes + "<br><span>minutes</span>");
  $(".seconds").html(seconds + "<br><span>seconds</span>");  

}

setInterval(makeTimer, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="row countdown-box" style="top: 0px">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2 id="countdown" class="days">24<br>                        <span>days</span></h2>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2 id="countdown">:</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2 id="countdown" class="hours">06<br><span>hours</span></h2>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2 id="countdown">:</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2 id="countdown" class="minutes">22<br><span>minutes</span></h2>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2 id="countdown">:</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2 id="countdown" class="seconds">59<br><span>seconds</span></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You passed `.<class>` selectors in the jquery when in the HTML you actuall use ID type. I recommend you use this instead:

```
$("#days").html(days + "<br><span>days</span>");
$("#hours").html(hours + "<br><span>hours</span>");
$("#minutes").html(minutes + "<br><span>minutes</span>");
$("#seconds").html(seconds + "<br><span>seconds</span>");
```